# QML: Can I rounded the start and end point of an arc painted with canvas

Tags: c++, qt, canvas, geometry, qml

How can I rounded the end and the start line of this arc painted with canvas in QML?

```
Canvas
{
    id: canvas
    property real degree: 180
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPaint:
    {
        var ctx = getContext("2d")
        var x = 90
        var y = 90
        var radius = 85
        var startAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * 270
        var fullAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * (270 + 360)
        var progressAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * (270 + degree)
        ctx.lineWidth = 5
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, progressAngle)
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red"
        ctx.stroke()
    }
}
```

[image: Result of QML up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas has `lineCap` property:

```
ctx.lineCap = "round";
```

That should do it. Note that it's pure js and not particularly related to QML so you'll probably have better luck searching for stuff like that without c++ and qml keywords.